# jQuery submit event function return value

Tags: ajax, forms, jquery

I have a function hooked on a `$('form').submit()` event.

This function will fire an ajax request and update the document.

I want to make it it so if an ajax error occurs the form continues to be submitted normally. Is this possible?

I tried `return fail_status;` on the end of the function (fail_status is a boolean variable that gets updated to "true" in the ajax "error" function), but it doesn't seem to work...

The code looks something like this:

```
$('form').submit(function(){
  var fail_status = false;

  $.ajax(

   ...

   error: function(){
     fail_status = true;
   }

   ...

  );

  return fail_status;
  // so if it's true the form should be submitted normally...
});
```

Comment: Please post your complete code so we can make the right assessment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that JQuery defaults to Asynchronous. This means that it is returning "fail_status" before it gets the server response.

Your best bet would be to have `error:` be a function that submits the form programatically.

```
error: function(){$('#myform').submit();}
```

**EDIT:** Try rewriting your function:

```
$('form').submit(function(retry){
    if(!retry){
        //do ajax
        error:function(){
              $('form').submit(true);
        }
    }
    return retry;
})
```

Comment: how can I do that? I tried `$('form').submit();` inside the error function and nothing happens..

Comment: `$('#myform').submit();` will just call his submit function again.  I think you mean `$('#myform')[0].submit()` or something like that to call submit on the form and not the `jquery` submit function.

Comment: ok I tried `$('form').unbind('submit').submit();` and it works :D tx all

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that AJAX is asynchronous.  Therefore, the `submit` function completes before the ajax call fails.  So you are returning false.

You will not be able to do this the way you have it unless you make the AJAX call synchronous.  This is generally a bad idea as the browser will hang while the request is sent.

The only other option I see is to submit the form from within the error function.

Answer (score 1):

You could separate the events:

```
$('#formSubmitButton').click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    $.ajax({
        // do ajax stuff here
        complete: function(){
            $('#myform').submit();
        }
    });

});
```

`complete` is unbiased to a successful or failed ajax response, as long as there is **a** response from the server. If you **only** want to submit the form on an ajax error, you'd put the submit event in the `error` method.

Comment: This method is not reliable,  as it's never preventing the submission when the form is submitted through `[Enter]` (at an input field).

Comment: Figured she was smart enough to handle that part.

Answer (score 1):

You either have to use a synchronous AJAX request (NOT recommended!), or use the code below.

The concept behind it:

- If `fail_status == false`, continue with the function (default)
- Use `ev.preventDefault()` to cancel the form submission. Set `ajax_request_made = true`
- Initiate AJAX call

  1. On success: Set `ajax_request_made = false`, to enable new form submissions
  2. On failure: Set `ajax_request_made = false`, to enable new form submissions,
               and set `fail_status = true`. Call the submit function again. Because this variable is set to `true`, the `ev.preventDefault()` statement is never reached, and the form submits.

```
var ajax_request_made = false,
    fail_status = false;
$('form').submit(function(ev){
  var the_form = this;
  if(fail_status){
      fail_status = false;
      return; //No prevent default, so the form is submitted.
  }

  ev.preventDefault(); // Cancel form submission
  if(ajax_request_made) { //Only allow one AJAX call at the form at a time
      return;       //Don't run the function when the request hasn't finished yet
  }

  ajax_request_made = true;
  $.ajax( ...
   complete: function(){
      ajax_request_made = false;  //Se
   },
   error: function(){
      ajax_request_made = false;
      fail_status = true;         // Set flag so that the form submits (see top)
      the_form.submit();          // Request form submission.
   } ...
  );
});
```